# Is it secure to give sitemap.xml 777 permission?

Tags: permissions

One of my colleagues told me to change the permissions of the `sitemap.xml` to 777 by using `chmod 0777`.  Is this secure?

The sitemap.xml is inside a media folder where our marketing team has access to via FTP. My fear is that they could just change the file, inject evil code and change its extension.

Comment: Do you really want any local user to be able to arbitrarily change the sitemap?

Comment: No I don't but my colleague gave me the "command"

Comment: This is not secure, but if you are still using FTP for file uploads, you should revise your security policy and practices thoroughly rather than clinging to such details as single file permissions.